# Blaming devs on gcc warnings (git blame + gcc output parsing)

Tags: git, gcc

My objective is to automate the process of blaming developers for any warnings they introduce with their commits. I have a git repo, and a build process that uses GCC (or clang) to compile the software.

What I would like is an automated script (or program) that does the job of parsing the GCC output for any warning, and then looks at the git history to retrieve the author of that piece of code.

There is something that I can use? Do you have a suggestion on how to implement it (e.g., there are automated GCC parser? A Clang plugin..?)

Thank you

Comment: More common would be to compare the output between 2 revisions and blame the author of that commit if new stuff appears.

Comment: But this does not include the beginning, in which there are already warnings.

Comment: Then use git bisect to find out when the issue was introduced, or just rebuild every old revision.